# Generate Reference Point in nsga3

Tags: python, matlab, evolutionary-algorithm

I am working on evolutionary algorithm and need a way to **generate reference point** (Das and Dennis approach)  in python. I have no idea and struck in this part can somebody please help to write this code.Thanks in advance I have matlab code but not understanding it how to convert to python.

```
function Zr = GenerateReferencePoints(M, p)

    Zr = GetFixedRowSumIntegerMatrix(M, p)' / 4;  #Not understanding the use of {'} 

end

function A = GetFixedRowSumIntegerMatrix(M, RowSum)

    if M < 1
        error('M cannot be less than 1.');
    end

    if floor(M) ~= M
        error('M must be an integer.');
    end

    if M == 1
        A = RowSum;
        return;
    end

    A = [];
    for i = 0:RowSum
        B = GetFixedRowSumIntegerMatrix(M - 1, RowSum - i);
        A = [A; i*ones(size(B,1),1) B]; #What is this function doing not getting it
    end

end
```

I don't understand **RowSum**  used for which purpose it is used